# Sinatra breaks driver.navigate.to in selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, sinatra

I try to make simple Selenium script using Ruby and I use Sinatra for net interaction. Script needs to get data with POST (I make link for driver.navigate.to using this data).
But when I use driver.navigate.to in post block it raise "Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:4444 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 4444):"

What can I do for fixing that?

```
post "/" do
    begin
      driver = $driver
      wait = $wait
      data = request.body.read
      person = MyClient.new(driver, wait, data)

    driver.navigate.to person.link_maker

    begin
      wait.until { driver.find_element(:id, '_pwPrintWindow').displayed? }
    rescue
      popup = driver.find_elements(:class, 'x-window-bwrap')
      if popup.count != 0
        msg = popup[0].find_element(:class, 'ext-mb-content').text
      end
    end

    person.accept_license

    rescue
      "500"
      end
  end
```

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:4444
>   (No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 4444):
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in
>   connect'  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:879:in`block in
>   connect'  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in`connect'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in`start'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.5.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:124:in`
>   response_for'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.5.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:78:in
>   `request'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.5.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.5.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:170:in
>   `execute'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.5.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:537:in`
>   execute'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.5.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:59:in
>   `get'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.5.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in`
>   to'  C:/Users/Nerewar/RubymineProjects/Korona/main.rb:95:in `block in
>   <top (required)>'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1632:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1632:in
>   `block in compile!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:991:in`block (3 levels) in route!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1010:in
>   `route_eval'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:991:in`block (2 levels) in route!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1037:in
>   `block in process_route'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1035:in`
>   catch'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1035:in
>   `process_route'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:989:in`block in route!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:988:in `each'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:988:in`route!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1094:in
>   `block in dispatch!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in`
>   block in invoke'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in
>   `catch'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in`
>   invoke'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1091:in
>   `dispatch!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:923:in`block in call!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in
>   `block in invoke'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in`
>   catch'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in
>   `invoke'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:923:in`call!'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:913:in `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in`call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in
>   `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:26:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in
>   `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in
>   `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/common_logger.rb:33:in
>   `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:231:in`call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:224:in `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in
>   `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:22:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:194:in `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1955:in`
>   call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1499:in
>   `block in call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1726:in`
>   synchronize'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1499:in
>   `call'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in`
>   block in pre_process'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in
>   `catch'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in`
>   pre_process'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:50:in
>   `block in process'
>     C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:1076:in`
>   block in spawn_threadpool'

Comment: Post complete exception stack trace